# Creating an algorithm to solve a problem in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**Algorithm Objective:**

link to the pictures i took while giving the amazon interview:

[https://boards.wetransfer.com/board/shl7w5z1e62os7nwv20190618224258/latest][pictures]

Eight houses, represented as cells, are arranged in a straight line. Each day every cell competes with its adjacent cells(neighbors). An integer value of 1 represents an active cell and a value of 0 represents an inactive cell. If the neighbors on both sides of a cell are either active or inactive, the cell becomes inactive on the next day, otherwise the cell becomes active. The two cell on each end have a single a single adjacent cell, so assume that the unoccupied space on the opposite side is an inactive cell. Even after updating the cell state, consider its previous state when updating the state of other cells. The state information of all cells should be updated simultaneously.

Create an algorithm to output the state of the cells after the given number of days.

**Input:**

The input to the function/method consists of two arguments:
`states`, a list of integers representing the current state of cells,
`days`,an integer representing the number of days.

**Output:**

Return a list of integers representing the state of the cells after the given number of days

**Note:**

The elements of the list states contains 0s and 1s only

**TestCase 1:**

Input: `[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0] , 1`

Expected Return Value: `0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0`

TestCase 2:

Input: `[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1] , 2`

Expected Return Value: `0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0`

**What I Tried:**

```
def cellCompete(states, days):
    # WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
    il = 0; 
    tl = len(states);
    intialvalue = states
    results = []
    states = []
    for i in range(days):
      #first range
      if(intialvalue[il] != intialvalue[il+1]):
        print('value of index 0 is : ',reverse(intialvalue[il]))
        results.append(reverse(intialvalue[il]))
      else:
        print('value of index 0 is :', intialvalue[il])
        results.append(intialvalue[il])
      print("-------------------")  

      #range middle
      while il < tl-2:
        if(intialvalue[il] != intialvalue[il+1] or intialvalue[il+1] != intialvalue[il+2]):
          print('value of index',il+1,'is : ',reverse(intialvalue[il+1]))
          results.append(reverse(intialvalue[il+1]))
        else:
          print('value of index', il+1,'is :', intialvalue[il+1])
          results.append(intialvalue[il+1])
        print("-------------------") 
        il += 1

      #range last
      if(intialvalue[tl-2] != intialvalue[tl-1]):
        print('value of index',tl-1,'is : ',reverse(intialvalue[tl-1]))
        results.append(reverse(intialvalue[tl-1]))
      else:
        print('value of index',tl-1,'is :', intialvalue[tl-1])
        results.append(intialvalue[tl-1])
      print("-------------------")  

      print('Input: ',intialvalue)
      print('Results: ',results)
      initialvalue = results

def reverse(val):
    if(val == 0):
      return 1
    elif(val == 1):
      return 0
print("-------------------------Test case 1--------------------")
cellCompete([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],1)
print("-------------------------Test case 2--------------------")
cellCompete([1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],2)
```

I am relatively new to python and i could not complete this algorithm for the second case on this python

Comment: Is this an assignment/homework? Did you read about how to ask for help with code - you need to edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve which your current question does _not_ include.

Comment: no it was an interview question asked on amazon and they did not have the option for php so i chose python

Comment: I don't really understand. Do you mean that if one of the cell's neighbors are active, the cell became active?

Comment: That’s (1-dimensional) life....

Comment: Okay I get it - so one should be active and the other one inactive in order to make the current cell active.

Comment: @barny, This is the link to the picture i took for the interview question has been updated to the question and i have typed exactly what they asked in the question.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that asking publicly for the answer to an interview question is the best way to ensure that you pass the interview. Wouldn't it be better (as in morally better, e.g. more honest) to write the code entirely yourself? And wouldn't it be better (as in is it good to help someone give someone elese's code as their own answer) for the 'answerers' to back off and let you write it yourself?

Comment: @barny I guess the interview is already over and the OP wants to learn how to solve similar problems in the future.

Comment: @Selcuk Hmm. Do you think so? Not so sure. Ah the OP added some evidence to support your proposition. Still, IMO in the longer term they'd be better served (as in better serve themselves) by persisting and learning to solve this themself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cell Compete Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171403/cell-compete-problems)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a much shorter routine that solves your problem.

```
def cellCompete(states, days):
    n = len(states)
    for day in range(days):
        houses = [0] + states + [0]
        states = [houses[i-1] ^ houses[i+1] for i in range(1, n+1)]
    return states

print(cellCompete([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0] , 1))
print(cellCompete([1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1] , 2))
```

The printout from that is what you want (though with list brackets included):

```
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

This routine adds sentinel zeros to each end of the list of house states. It then uses a list comprehension to find the houses' new states. All this is repeated the proper number of times before the house states are returned.

The calculation of a new house state is `houses[i-1] ^ houses[i+1]`. That character `^` is bitwise exclusive-or. The value is `1` if the two values are different and `0` if the two values are the same. That is just what is needed in your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive version:

```
def cell_compete(states, days):
    s = [0] + states + [0]
    states = [i ^ j for i, j in zip(s[:-2], s[2:])]  # Thanks @RoyDaulton
    return cell_compete(states, days - 1) if days > 1 else states
```

A non-recursive version that also avoids extending the list by adding edge `[0]` elements would be:

```
def cell_compete(states, days):
    for _ in range(days):
        states = [states[1]] + [i ^ j for i, j in zip(states[:-2], states[2:])] + [states[-2]]
    return states
```

Comment: A nice use of `zip` to be more pythonic and avoid the use of indices. And the use of recursion shortens the code. You could shorten the calculation by using `i ^ j` rather than `int(bool(i - j))`.

Comment: The only issue here with recursion is that python doesn't have tail call optimization. So with a high enough days, it will reach the max recursion limit.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```
def cellCompete(states,days):
    newstates = []
    added_states = [0] + states + [0]
    for counter,value in enumerate(states):
        newstates.append(int((added_states[counter] != added_states[counter+2])))

    if days > 1:
        return cellCompete(newstates,days-1)
    else:
        return newstates

print(cellCompete([1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1],2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Rory's using XOR but without the need for the internal comprehension. Bit shift the number by 2 and clip the extra bit from the left by taking the modulus:

```
def process(state, r):
    n = int(''.join(map(str,state)), 2)
    for i in range(r):
        n = ((n ^ n << 2) >> 1) % 256

    return list(map(int,format(n, "08b")))

process([1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1], 2)
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

process([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0] , 1)
# [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

While everyone is trying to make the simplest version possible here's a more complex version. It's pretty similar to the previous answers except that instead of keeping the state in the function, this solution is formed of 2 two part. One is the utility function that we want to be able to call, the other is a generator that keep tracks of the states.

The main difference here is that the generator takes a comparator and an initial state that will be mutated. The generator can also be sent as a parameter so the generator can help divide the logic of how many state you want to generate and to have a way to mutate from an actual state indefinitely.

```
def mutator(state, comparator):
    while True:
        states = [0] + state + [0]
        state = [
            comparator(states[cellid-1], states[cellid+1])
            for cellid in range(1, len(states)-1)
        ]
        yield state

def cellCompete(states, days):
    generator = mutator(states, lambda x, y: x ^ y)

    for idx, states in enumerate(generator):
        if idx+2 > days:
            break

    return states

print(cellCompete([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0] , 1))
print(cellCompete([1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1] , 2))
```

Also, I added a comparator that allow us to have some kind of undefined operation on both elements. It can allow the code to be extended beyond the initial spec. It's obviously a superfluous implementation but as mentioned, it's supposed to be an interview answer and as much as I like to see a straight to the point answer, if someone can come up with a flexible answer in the same timeframe, then why not.