# having an issue with cellCompete problem in Javascript, need some assistance

Tags: javascript

So the instructions for this one are:

> There is a colony of 8 cells arranged in a straight line where each day every cell competes with its adjacent cells(neighbour). Each day, for each cell, if its neighbours are both active or both inactive, the cell becomes inactive the next day, otherwise it becomes active the next day.
>
> Assumptions
>   The two cells on the ends have single adjacent cell, so the other adjacent cell can be assumsed to be always inactive. Even after updating the cell state. consider its previous state for updating the state of other cells. Update the cell information of all cells simultaneously.
>
> Write a function cellCompete which takes takes one 8 element array of integers cells representing the current state of 8 cells and one integer days representing the number of days to simulate. An integer value of 1 represents an active cell and value of 0 represents an inactive cell.

I wrote a recursive function that spreads states into newStates, and modifies newStates by iterating through states and checking adjacent elements.

My result is not matching what the test cases are saying should be output.

For example:

cellCompete([1,1,1,0,1,1,1], 2)) //-> should return [0,0,0,0,1,1,0], but instead returns [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]

my code is

```
function cellCompete(states, days){
    //base case, if days === 0, return states.
    if(days === 0) return states;
    let newStates = [...states];
      // iterate through states with i
      for(let i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
          //if i is not on first or last element in the array
          if (i !== 0 && i !== states.length - 1){
            if(states[i-1] === states[i+1]){
               newStates[i] = 0
            } else {
              //if not equal, cell becomes inactive
              newStates[i] = 1
            }  
          }
          //if first element check next against 0
          if(i === 0){
            if(states[i+1] === 0){
              newStates[0] = 0
            } else {
              newStates[0] = 1
            }
          }
          //if last element check previous against 0
          if(i === states.length - 1){
            if(states[i-1] === 0){
              newStates[i] = 0
            } else {
              newStates[i] = 1
            }
          }
      }
    return cellCompete(newStates, --days)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cellCompete([1,1,1,0,1,1,1], 2) should return [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

day 1: [1,0,1,0,1,0,1]

day 2: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

I think you are giving the wrong inputs since your input only contains 7 cells, while the question states 8 cells.

cellCompete([1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1], 2) returns [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but you failed to enter the input data, it must be 8 elements, not 7.

Check it out below:

```js
function cellCompete(states, days){
    //base case, if days === 0, return states.
    if(days === 0) return states;
    let newStates = [...states];
      // iterate through states with i
      for(let i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
          //if i is not on first or last element in the array
          if (i !== 0 && i !== states.length - 1){
            if(states[i-1] === states[i+1]){
               newStates[i] = 0
            } else {
              //if not equal, cell becomes inactive
              newStates[i] = 1
            }  
          }
          //if first element check next against 0
          if(i === 0){
            if(states[i+1] === 0){
              newStates[0] = 0
            } else {
              newStates[0] = 1
            }
          }
          //if last element check previous against 0
          if(i === states.length - 1){
            if(states[i-1] === 0){
              newStates[i] = 0
            } else {
              newStates[i] = 1
            }
          }
      }
    return cellCompete(newStates, --days)
}

console.log(...cellCompete([1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0], 1));
console.log(...cellCompete([1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1], 2));
```

I have also tried other cases provided by this same exercise in this [link](https://www.faceprep.in/article/amcat-automata-coding-question).

In addition, this question is [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171403/cell-compete-problems).